# django - queryset in modelForm

Tags: django, django-queryset, modelform

I need to filter `Food` model by datetime in `forms.py`, but I do not know how to do it. Could anyone help me?

models.py

```
class Food(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Food"
        verbose_name_plural = "Foods"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.food_name

    food_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Food Name", max_length=50)
    serve_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Serve Date")
```

forms.py

```
class Reserve(forms.ModelForm):
    food_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Food.objects.all(), 
        widget=forms.Select(), 
        empty_label=u"برای انتخاب غذا کلیک کنید",
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = ('food_count', 'food_name')
```

Comment: have you tried or researched anything?

Comment: @Sayse yes ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter your queryset by using lte(Less than or equal) or gte(Greater than or equal) in following way:-

```
queryset=Food.objects.filter(serve_date__lte='2006-01-01')
```

or

```
queryset=Food.objects.filter(serve_date__gte='2006-01-01')
```

Comment: Yes there is you can pass it as 127.0.0.1:8000/2016-11-08  and then in your view you can replace '-' by '/' because '/' will conflict with the url

Comment: my problem is there. how can pass datetime variables (year, month, day) to form?

Comment: I've edited queryset. queryset=Food.objects.filter(serve_date__date = serve_date). but retuen: "serve_date not defined"

Comment: You can refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/ to find a more precise answer