# Modelchoicefield Queryset Confusion

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates

All,

I'm new to Django and have been doing pretty good so far but this one has me stumped.  I'm trying to utilize ModelChoiceField for a number of records that have the same name.  I'm using Postgresql so I was able to determine that I need to use the distinct command and that is working perfectly.  The records in my dropdown are all stripped down to just one version of each of the records.  However, when I try to get all of the versions of a particular record, that's where I'm getting lost.  I am able to get the detail of each record if I don't use distinct via a DetailView, but I am really trying to get all versions of each record on the screen after the modelchoicefield.

Here is my form:

```
class History(forms.Form):

        dropdown = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=History.objects.all())

        def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
            super(History, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['dropdown'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'choices1'
            self.fields['dropdown'].empty_label = ''

            qs = History.objects.all().distinct('record_name')
            self.fields['dropdown'].queryset = qs
```

I am ultimately trying to get a view the queryset on the screen via my template.  I have tried several different versions of code in the template but nothing seems to work.  If I use the CBV DetailView without distinct I can get all of the records with their detail view fine.  However, that's not what I'm trying to do.  I have played with several versions of the queryset command in the template as I found several questions similar to mine but can't seem to get it to work.  I found a couple of references to something similar to:

```
{% for record in form.history.field.queryset %}
etc.
{% endfor %}
```

But can't seem to get it to work in my Django template.  Any and all help is appreciated!  Thank you in advance!

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly, then it is about to display data records which depend on the current value of your dropdown box?

Comment: @Max M Yes that's what I'm trying to do, get the value of what the user selects from the dropdown box and then display all of the records that have that same name on the next screen.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'd either suggest

**a)** to put the value of your dropdown field into your url matching. [See the django docs for named groups in URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#named-groups). Additionally, you could add an `onchange` event to your dropdown-field which redirects to `<current url>/<value of dropdown>` or simply change the value of (if existing) buttons which links to the following page. **Caution:** With this solution you must ensure that the values of your dropdown field matches **url-format** ([django's slugify might be useful for this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify)).

or

**b)** to add your dropdown field to your input form or as input field. Then you can extract the value of your dropdown with:

```
try:
    dropdown_value = request.POST['dropdown-field-name'] # dict-error if field is not in request.POST
except:
    # some error actions
```

then you can add this value as filter to your queryset:

```
def get_queryset(self, dropdown_value=None):
    # ...
    qs = qs.filter('field-name' = dropdown_value) # possibly no/wrong results if dropdown_value is corrupted or manipulated
```

Comment: @ Max M..Thank you for helping me.  I will try those examples out and see what happens.  In reviewing your suggestions, they are a little more advanced than what I was thinking.  As an example, if the dropdown list had A,B, and C in it...I was hoping to then have the user select one of those and click submit.  Then the next screen would be a list of all of the versions of A ( assuming user selected A).  I tried this with the CB list view, but got the entire list.  Is there a way other than what you've suggested to just get a list of the A entries?  Or not possible because of queryset?

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40543879/8389244). It might gives the answer you're looking for - or you can mix it up with one of mine suggestions.

Comment: Unfortinately none of the suggestions above seem to help.  I have stumbled across the to_field_name option for ModelChoiceField, and it is essentially giving me the name of the record in the dropdown, but I can't seem to figure out how to get all of the records with the same name on the next screen.  I can get them individually when I remove distinct, but that's not what I'm trying to do.  I essentially just want to get the "list" of records with the same name and then click and get the details.  I seem to be able to get the whole list but not the subset I'm looking for.  Any other ideas?